# Не подключается отдельный файл CSS для IE, помогите решить проблему

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, internet-explorer

Вот сайт - http://websterjoy.tk/  там в области <head> есть код, которым я подключаю отдельный css для ie :

```
    <!--[if lte IE 9]> .... <![endif]-->,
```

но файл в IE не работает. НО! если же прописать так:

```
    <!--[if IE]> .... <![endif]-->,
```

то все работает! кто знает, в чем причина?

Comment: С какой версии ие заходите?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]> .... <![endif]-->
```

если у тебя IE 10+ то уже не будет работать.

```
<!--[if IE]> .... <![endif]-->
```

Для всех версий IE.

Начиная с IE8 номер версии, отправляемый браузером можно изменять через Средства разработчика. Если режим браузера установить на IE7, хотя используется IE 9, будет считаться как 7й